# Metal compute kernel and loading screen

Tags: ios, uikit, uiviewanimation, metal

I have created a metal compute kernel that takes several seconds to execute. While the metal kernel is running a UIKit-based loading screen is being presented. The metal kernel does **not** run on the main thread and the loading screen runs a simple UIView block based animation.

The loading screen animation freezes for some time and there is obvious stuttering while the kernel executes.

Is there a way to fix that (except the obvious solution of removing the loading animation)?

Comment: iOS uses the GPU to draw the screen, so if you're keeping the GPU occupied with a long-running compute kernel, then how is the GPU also supposed to draw to the screen? But I'm curious what sort of compute kernel you're using if it takes several seconds... perhaps rewriting this to use the CPU is more efficient.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans when the same code runs on the CPU, takes about 15 times more to execute. I know what is the cause of the problem and I agree with you. But I want to know if there is a metal related technique to apply in order to have animations. Is there a way to support in time parallelism on the GPU like in the CPU world??

Comment: Is it possible to break up the compute work by dispatching threadgroups across a sequence of command buffers, instead of encoding all of the work as a single, long-running command?

Comment: @warrenm I am afraid that it is not, but I ll give it a try. Thanks anyway!

Comment: When you say it takes 15 times longer to execute on the CPU, is this a naive implementation using lots of loops or is it optimized using Accelerate operations?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans You re right on this point. The code is not optimised with Accelerate operations, but I would like to avoid rewriting the code one more time... Moreover, I strongly believe that the performance will not be superior than the current GPU implementation but I will have the loading option available. I think this feature goes to version 2.0 of the app :).Thank you.

Comment: I'm far too late to comment on this, but did you try breaking up your processing into smaller chunks in order to sort-of cooperatively multitask? `dispatchThreads:threadsPerThreadgroup:` allows you to dispatch over a smaller region than the full texture, and you can use a uniform buffer to provide an offset to your kernel function.

Comment: @Tommy unfortunately no. I ended using the default UIActivityIndicatorView. This view is magic. It always spins even when the GPU/CPU is at full load. I also believe that with no documentation and/or samples finding a solution to this problem is a lifetime project.